# SPARQL query on sdmx-dimension:refPeriod

Tags: sparql, rdf, sdmx, openlink-virtuoso

I'm trying to run a SPARQL query on sdmx-dimension:refPeriod in order to get the date.
The triple that contains the date is in the format:

```
exp:obs0 sdmx-dimension:refPeriod exp:2020-08-03
```

so when I go to extract the date with:

```
SELECT ?date 
WHERE {
? obs sdmx-dimension:refPeriod ?date
}
```

I get the IRI of the resource "date":

```
http://example.org/2020-02-24
```

Instead I would only like to get the date value.

Is there any way in SPARQL to do it? Or, after receiving the results of the query, do I have to go to parse the result in order to get only the date?

Comment: is there no value attached to the resource? I mean, sometimes the literal value itself is attached by a separate RDF triple.

Comment: if not, `BIND( xsd:date( replace( str(?date), ''http://example.org/", "")  ) as ?dateVal)` could work

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks you, it works!